# How to echo a variable which is returned in a function in unlink method

Tags: php

I want to unlink image, and I am getting the image name that is stored in the database. I've used User class to get the users info form database where I've and avatar column which has the image name stored in it.

The function looks like this

```
public function avatar(){
            $userId = $_SESSION['userId'];
            if($this->Query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?',[$userId])){
                if($this->rowCount() > 0){
                    $row = $this->fetch();
                        $avatar = $row->avatar;
                        return  $avatar;
                }
            }
        }
```

And I want to call out the variable in unlink function but it returns error if I use it like this

```
@unlink('../../assets/img/avatar'. echo $user->avatar());
```

How can  call the image name from db in that function?

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: `@unlink('../../assets/img/avatar'. $user->avatar());`?

Comment: Tried that does not work

Comment: What error do you got? You may need to remove the `@` before the `unlink` to see

Comment: Syntax error, when I remove the echo the error is gone

Comment: So, it solved your problem?

Comment: But the image name is not printing, so i used echo

Comment: `unlink` is used to delete a file. Do you want to write the image name or delete the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To delete the file:**

```
@unlink('../../assets/img/avatar/' . $user->avatar());
```

**To write the image name:**

```
echo $user->avatar();
```

**To display the image:**

```
echo "<img src='../../assets/img/avatar/'" . $user->avatar() . "' />";
```

**or:**

```
echo "<img src='" . $user->avatar() . "' />";
```

Comment: I just want to delete the file and when I just write it with that function it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct path to that file?